# Minimum width (CSS)

Tags: css, html, width, hyperlink

I've got a header (width 100%) containing some links. When you resize the browser, the links will be displayed beneath each other when there is little space. I know I can use min-width for this problem, but I don't know the exact amount of space that the links will use, because they are dynamic. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is like this

```
<div id="links">
   <a href="#link">Link</a>
   <a href="#link">Link</a>
   <a href="#link">Link</a>
</div>
```

You could have this CSS:

```
#links {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will prevent the links from wrapping to another line.

If your code not like this, you should post it with your question.

Comment: Yay, it works!!! :) Many, many thanks! But since the width was 100%, and I scroll to the right, I can't see the background of the parent div. How can I fix that?

Comment: Just add the `white-space:nowrap;` to the parent div instead.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a lot of detail, but it sounds to me like you need something to stop them wrapping.

In that case, you could try this:

```
.parentelement {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

which would apply to the container element of the fields you wanted to keep in line.